# Access json array value in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am getting following json response from google analytic,
 "rows":
    [
        [
            "New Visitor",
            "100.0",
            "6"
        ],
        [
            "Returning Visitor",
            "0.0",
            "14"
        ]
    ]

I want to access those value in angularjs Is any one can solve my problem??

Comment: It's difficult to answer without any code snippets. Can you please show what have you done so far and what part of the code is causing trouble?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ng-repeat primitive twice :

```
<div ng-repeat="visitor in ctrl.rows">
  <div ng-repeat="row in visitor">
    {{row}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Displaying :
New Visitor
100.0
6
Returning Visitor
0.0
14

Answer (score 0):

Just do this :

// in your controller where you are getting the json response from your service :

```
.controller(function($scope, analyticsService) {
   $scope.rows = "";
   // I am assuming you have your $http (angular ajax wrapper) call in a service which I will call analyticsService for example purposes
   analyticsService.getResults(function(result){
   $scope.rows = JSON.parse(result.rows);
 })
}
```